# Why am I getting file not found error when I run this app?

Tags: android

Can any tell me why I found this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
G:\andriodproject\MyApplication2\app\libs\picasoo-2.5.2.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: Your answer is in your question. `The system cannot find the file specified`. Might be the path is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **picasoo-2.5.2.jar** remains in directory. If you found it, you can try to Upgrade build tools build gradle version with.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
            }
```

and clear project

Answer (score 0):

Using the path of

> G:\andriodproject\MyApplication2\app\libs\picasoo-2.5.2.jar

the file of

> picasoo-2.5.2.jar

was not found. The file with this name might be missing or privilege to one or more folders in the path might be missing.